# thead with one td (full width) and tbody with 2 columns (width not depending on thead)

Tags: html, html-table

Okay, long title short story. I've got a table structured like this:

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr><th>longer Heading with a width of 100%</th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr><td>cell 1</td><td>cell 2</tr>
<tr><td>cell 3</td><td>cell 4</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

And I'd like the th to be full width and not change the width of the table cells. 
I guess there's some CSS display property that would make this possible but I haven't found a working solution yet.

Comment: Done, found the caption tag which is placed straight after the beginning of the table

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
<table>
  <thead>
     <tr><th colspan="2">longer Heading with a width of 100%</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
     <tr><td>cell 1</td><td>cell 2 </td></tr>
      <tr><td>cell 3</td><td>cell 4 </td></tr>
 </tbody>
```

use of `colspan` will do the trick for you

Answer (score 7):

This?

```
<th colspan="2">...</th>
```

Answer (score 5):

It's easier than that: You just need a colspan on your `th` element.
Colspan defines, how many cells the element extends:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr><th colspan="2">longer Heading with a width of 100%</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>cell 1</td><td>cell 2</tr>
        <tr><td>cell 3</td><td>cell 4</tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

<kbd>**[See my Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/frontender/UHK6D/)**</kbd>